# On mouseup get target of div below element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Say I have some markup like this:

```
<div class="something1">
  Content 1
</div>
<div class="something2">
  Content 2
</div>

<div class="drag">
  Draggable div
</div>
```

Now, I've written some jQuery to allow the `.drag` div to be dragged. At the end of the drag I do something like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseup',function(e){
  console.log(e.target); 
});
```

When I drag the div over `.something1`, the answer to `e.target` I would like is `.something1`. Instead, because `.drag` is being dragged under the mouse, when the `mouseup` function executes, the target is still the `.drag` div.

How do I see what div the mouse is over during the mouseup, ignoring the div being dragged? Equally, how do I use this method to see what div is being hovered over whilst the dragging is happening?

(If it helps to know, I'm trying to build drag and drop functionality)

Comment: why don't you use the jquey ui draggable component. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#default

Comment: I might. But I would like to understand how to do this as there are a few projects it will come in useful and I don't like to keep using plugins (sometimes bulky) when I can just write the code I need.

Comment: you could try to locate the element by using document.elementFromPoint(x, y); the last position could be reteived from the mousemove while the mouse was down. you could also look at this drag & drop tutorial http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dragdrop.html

Answer (score 3):

You cannot fire a mouseup event because `.drag` isn't a child node of something1 or something2, then, always you will get `e.target = .drag`

But you have another options
If you write your own code:
I added an `id` attribute to each div for search reasons. (see js below)

```
<div class="something1" id="something">
    Content 1
</div>
<div class="something2" id="something">
    Content 2
</div>

<div class="drag">
    Drag me
</div>
```

To know which `div` you are, is necessary to know the mouse position and the `div`'s area. See the next

```js
function getHoverElement(x,y){
    element = "none";
    $('div#something').each(function(i){
        el = this;
        el_left = $(el).offset().left;
        el_right= $(el).offset().left + $(el).width();
        el_top = $(el).offset().top;
        el_bottom = $(el).offset().top + $(el).height();

        if (x >= el_left && x <= el_right) {
            if (y >= el_top && y <= el_bottom) {
                element = $(el).attr('class');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return element;
}
```

`x` and `y` are passed from `mouseup` event. See the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/PELDF/1)

Obviously, this solution is based on mouse position only and isn't considered the margins of draggable element. So, if you need to refine the code you need to look at the `drag` element borders.

Another solution is to use `draggable`/`droppable` methods from jquery-ui that cover this issue.

```
$(".something1, .something2").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

See the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/w4jAx/)

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! Adding this to a barebones replacement of jQuery's draggable was exactly the ticket to solving a simple drag n drop JS module without the bloat of jQuery UI.

Comment: you just leaked a bunch of variables to global